# Powershell scripting for creating lists Online version of SharePoint 2013?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I would like to know if we can script list creation and modification (i.e adding, deleting columns, etc..) using PowerShell for SharePoint online.

http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2012/06/07/scripting-sharepoint-online-with-powershell-using-client-object-model/

The link above explains how to do that for SharePoint 2010 (online), I would like to know if something like this exists for SharePoint 2013(online).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit a searching, found out that we could do that by using PowerShell and .Net CSOM.

Thanks to the link below.

http://www.blumenthalit.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=171